# Discretisation by FVM with triangulare mesh

Tags: finite-volume, electromagnetism

I work on electromagnetic modeling, and I use the finite volume method as a tool, so I want to develop code by the modified finite volume method (with triangular mesh), my problem studied is in a permeable environment (ferromagnetic materials).

in first i try to discetize  $-\mathrm{div}(\mathrm{grad}(A)=\mu_0(J + \mathrm{rot}(M))$ by fvm with rectangular mesh, (see picture)
[image]

#### My question Now

I search to determine the magnetic vector potential $A$ at the centers of gravity of the triangles,

my problem is in how to discretize this equation above by FVM triagnular like in rectangular mesh

$$-\left(\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial y^2}\right)  = \mu_0 \left(J_S + \frac{\partial M_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M_x}{\partial y}\right)\, .$$

Comment: Could you please type your equations using MathJax (LaTeX syntax)?

Comment: I m a new contributor to this site. it's not clear my equation ??

Comment: I edited the equations, please review that there isn't any mistake. For future questions, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It's very difficult to say anything useful on your question. In short, your question reads like this: "I'm trying to solve A. I have a method that works in a special case. Now I want to do B, but I found difficulties." What specifically are your difficulties? What works and what doesn't? What have you tried to figure out how to do B, and which step are you stuck with? We really can't look into your head to find the answer to these questions! :-)

Comment: nicoguaro ,thanks, yes its correct. but  do you understand my question

Comment: Wolfgang Bangerth , I apologize for my language, so  in short , I want to get a discritiszation of the equation above by FVM with triangular mesh , its clear now?

Comment: @ Ali Hammouche For FVM you need to evaluate fluxes through cell faces. These fluxes are related to partial derivatives of some quantity. Whatever shape the cells are, if you have a bunch of grid points nearby, you can evaluate all derivatives that you need.